How to fix IPv4 routes in Network Manager `nmcli` so I don't have to manually `ip route delete` the route Network Manager creates?
I have a network device with both:

Cellular Internet via modem (I need this to work 100% of the time for Internet access).
Ethernet interface for Modbus TCP connection.

The cellular connection is created with this command:
$ sudo nmcli c add type gsm con-name telus \
    ipv4.dns '8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4' autoconnect yes \
    ifname 'cdc-wdm0' apn 'isp.telus.com' \
    ipv4.route-metric 1

$ sudo nmcli con up telus

The Modbus ethernet connection is created like this:
$ sudo nmcli con add type ethernet con-name modbus \
    ifname enp1s0 connection.autoconnect yes \
    ipv4.never-default yes \
    ipv4.addresses '10.1.9.7/16, 10.1.9.7/8' \
    ipv4.routes '10.1.0.0/16 10.1.10.1, 10.0.0.0/8 10.1.10.1' \
    ipv4.route-metric 800

$ sudo nmcli con up modbus

At this point, the ping test fails:
$ ping -c 1 10.65.3.5
PING 10.65.3.5 (10.65.3.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
^C
--- 10.65.3.5 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms

The Hacky Solution:
I have to manually delete one of the routes Network Manager creates with ip route:
$ sudo ip route delete 10.0.0.0/8 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.9.7 metric 800

Great success!
$ ping -c 1 10.65.3.5
PING 10.65.3.5 (10.65.3.5) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.65.3.5: icmp_seq=1 ttl=126 time=117 ms

--- 10.65.3.5 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 117.203/117.203/117.203/0.000 ms

But I'm worried...
I think this solution is only temporary, until Network Manager puts the route back again...
How to persist the working configuration so I don't have to manually delete the route? It keeps popping up again, because Network Manager keeps putting it back.
Working routes, after deleting the bad route that makes the ping test fail:
$ sudo ip route delete 10.0.0.0/8 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.9.7 metric 800

$ ip route
default via 10.96.241.146 dev wwan proto static metric 1
10.0.0.0/8 via 10.1.10.1 dev enp1s0 proto static metric 800
10.1.0.0/16 via 10.1.10.1 dev enp1s0 proto static metric 800
10.1.0.0/16 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.9.7 metric 800
10.96.241.144/30 dev wwan proto kernel scope link src 10.96.241.145 metric 1

Note the following route is not there anymore, but it keeps getting put back...
10.0.0.0/8 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.9.7 metric 800

Thanks to this answer, I've since added the following script to "/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/99-kill-bad-route.sh", which is also kind of hacky...
#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "enp1s0" ] && [ "$2" == "up" ]; then
    ip route del 10.0.0.0/8 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.9.7 metric 800
fi

Can the above solution be accomplished with a Network Manager nmcli command instead?
Here's how I automated the solution with Python:
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess


def add_script_to_auto_delete_problem_route(
    counter: int,
    bad_network: str,
    ip_address: str,
    interface: str = "enp1s0",
) -> None:
    """
    sudo nano /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/9x-delete-problem-route.sh
    #!/bin/bash

    if [ "$1" == "enp1s0" ] && [ "$2" == "up" ]; then
        ip route del 10.0.0.0/8 dev enp1s0 proto kernel scope link src 10.1.9.7
    fi
    """
    file_path: Path = Path(
        f"/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/9{counter}-delete-problem-route-modbus.sh"
    )
    script: str = f"""#!/bin/bash

if [ "$1" == "{interface}" ] && [ "$2" == "up" ]; then
    ip route del {bad_network} dev {interface} proto kernel scope link src {ip_address}
fi
"""
    print(
        "Adding script to '%s' to delete problem route '%s'...",
        file_path,
        bad_network,
    )
    if not file_path.parent.exists():
        file_path.parent.mkdir(parents=True, exist_ok=True)
    if not file_path.exists():
        file_path.touch()
    with open(file_path, "w", encoding="utf-8") as file:
        file.write(script)

    # Make the file executable
    command_list: list = ["sudo", "chmod", "+x", str(file_path)]
    print("Running command '%s' to make the script executable...", command_list)
    subprocess.run(command_list, shell=False)

    return None


proto kernel usually suggests that NetworkManager did not create the route – the kernel did. Specifically, this is your "local subnet" route; Linux automatically created the 10.0.0.0/8 dev enp1s0 route because you have configured 10.1.9.7/8 as an IP address on that interface.
This is standard behavior for any IPv4 stack (indeed it's the sole purpose of specifying a netmask together with an IP address), so if you want to avoid it, it's best to not configure 10.1.9.7/8 as an IP address in the first place – especially when it's a duplicate of 10.1.9.7/16 on the same line.
